# Mootools and IE9

Tags: javascript, webforms, mootools, internet-explorer-9

Looks like the formcheck library is not working on IE9.

while these work on IE9:
http://mootools.net/demos/

these demos do not:
http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/

Should I convert to jQuery, wait for IE9 coming out of beta or is there some fix for this?

(I'm thinking of just waiting it out, but maybe doing more form-checking on the server side wouldn't be a bad idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the mootools version formcheck (it's very good!) uses. It seems that it's using mootools 1.2 (latest version is 1.3) and so it's why there could be some problems on IE9.

The http://mootools.net/demos/ are referring about the Form.Validator that is inside the more package.

However, I don't think formcheck will work on IE9 Beta. I'd write to the developer about the issue ;)

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work with 1.3, so that might just be the case.

Comment: you could also try to use formcheck with mootools 1.3 with 1.2 compat (see http://mootools.net/download)